# Base de dados ocupada

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvc

```
 public List<R> GetA(DateTime dataMov)
    {
        connection();
        List<R> menuList = new List<R>();

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT r.nome,r.cos,r.estoque, r.bala as 'balance', movimento, movimento, (estoque + r.balance) as 'diver'  FROM R_ATI r left join DR_DIA d on d.conta = r.cos where movimento = '" + dataMov.ToString("s") + "' and movimento = '" + dataMov.ToString("s") + "' and r.estoque <> 0.0", con))
            {
                var r = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                if (r.HasRows)
                {
                    foreach (DbDataRecord s in r)
                    {                            
                        menuList.Add(new Renda
                        {
                            papel = Convert.ToString(s["nome"]),
                            cos = Convert.ToString(s["cos"]),
                            curva = Convert.ToDouble(s["estoque"]),
                            curvaA = Convert.ToDouble(s["balance"]),
                            divergencia = Convert.ToDouble(s["divergencia"])


                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            con.Close();
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        { con.Close(); }

        return menuList;
    }
```

Pra montar essa grid uso mais de uma base de dados, ela está no meu model gostaria de saber como colocar um aviso para o usuario, avisando que quando essa lista nao aparecer na tela, isso indica que tem alguem usando a base de dados. Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para descobrir se o banco de dados está atualmente em uso, a maneira mais precisa seria descobrir se qualquer sessão tem qualquer bloqueio no banco de dados específico, consultando ***sys.dm_tran_locks***. Aqui está uma função auxiliar para retornar um bool se o banco de dados está em uso ou não:

```
bool BancoDeDadosEmUso(string NomeDoBancoDeDados)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("... sua string de conexão ..."))
    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
        sqlCmd.CommandText = @"select count(*) from sys.dm_tran_locks where resource_database_id = db_id(@NomeDoBancoDeDados);";

        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@NomeDoBancoDeDados", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128)
        {
            Value = NomeDoBancoDeDados
        });

        sqlConn.Open();
        int ContaSessao = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());

        if (ContaSessao > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Veja mais em:

[C# how to check if database is not busy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32956041/c-sharp-how-to-check-if-database-is-not-busy)